# Intellisense Auto-Conversion (dot to arrow)

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

After having worked with Eclipse CDT for quite some time, I've become accustomed to my IDE automatically converting a dot operator to an arrow when accessing members through a pointer to an object.

Is it possible to do this with Intellisense in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: "my IDE automatically converting a dot operator to an arrow when accessing members through a pointer to an object."  Dear lord what a horrible thing to put in an IDE - blurring the distinction in the coder's mind between an object and pointer...   You will probably need to write a custom extension for Visual Studio to parse and implement this for you which is a major pain in the butt...

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse Hahaha, I agree that it could certainly cause problems for someone learning the language, but for my case it's simply a matter of wanting to avoid some finger acrobatics. Definitely not important enough to bother writing a custom extension, though.

Comment: Visual Assist does this for me (on top of many other benefits). Although it is not free software. http://www.wholetomato.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be enabled in Visual Studio 2013 out-of-the-box, however we did add this feature (in Experimental status) in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC.

It can be enabled in Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C/C++ --> Experimental (or do Ctrl+Q for Quick Launch and type in "experimental") as "Member List Dot-To-Arrow".

[image: Experimental options page where the feature can be enabled]

This is how it looks like in action:

[image: Video demonstrating the feature]

Since this is "Experimental", feedback is most welcome :).

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/11/03/introducing-the-experimental-page-for-c-c-editor-tools.aspx

Comment: Hi. There's one problem with this feature. It doesn't work on smart pointers. Visual Assist fixed this by adding a feature "Convert dot to-> if operator -> is overloaded", please do the same. Thanks:)

Comment: @Phantom We intentionally do not trigger the feature if there are members available through dot, but the extra option you are suggesting overriding that may be a good idea. I will add it to our backlog. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work inside lambda functions. Also, why not replace the dot as soon as it is pressed (at least if no members are available through dot)?